# External monitor disconnects if MacBook Pro power adapter not plugged in

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

My MacBook Pro 2017 Function Keys is connected to my HP VH240a monitor via HDMI->Apple Multiport adapter. However, for some reason, when I take the MBP off the power adapter, after several seconds, the monitor screen goes black ("input not found"). If I wait several seconds, the monitor screen comes back, but then goes black again soon after. This just keeps repeating. If the MBP is connected to power, I can use the monitor no problem. Any ideas? The battery on the MBP is brand new (I just replaced it). Apple did tell me there seems to be an issue with one of my power sensors. Could that be it?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: There are no “power sensors” to fail.  There are *current sensing circuits” and if they failed, your MacBook would not work.  Is your power cable plugged into that multiport adapter?

Comment: @Allan Yes it is

Comment: Try plugging power into a port all by itself.

Comment: Is the laptop open or closed?

Comment: @Allan the whole idea is that I don't want to constantly have the MBP plugged in, even if it's connected to the monitor

Comment: @benwiggy open or closed, same issue

Comment: Plug it into a *different* port than where you adapter is plugged in.  You can disconnect it any time you like.

Comment: @Allan What I'm saying is that once I unplug the power (regardless of which port it's in), the monitor goes black, comes back, goes black, comes back, etc.

Comment: Is the port on the same side or opposite side?

Comment: @Allan the ports are all on one side

Comment: The way USB-C power works is there is a single chip that handles the ports.  If you have ports on only one side; one chip.  Two ports; there's two chips.  When you pull the power adapter, the Mac is no longer receiving and delivering power, but now only delivering power.  This transition isn't completely seamless; it can't be.   I'm sure if you used a powered hub with video or a dock this problem will dissapear.

Comment: @Allan Interesting. Is there a product you can recommend?

Comment: Try [Caldigit](https://www.caldigit.com/).  I’ve had good experiences with their TB 1/2 products though I haven’t used their TB 3/4 products, yet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Allan. Wow, they are expensive. I'm going to try this one instead https://www.amazon.com/Docking-Station-MacBook-Multiport-Ethernet/dp/B09WD3CZ9T/ref=sr_1_8?keywords=macbook%2Bpro%2Bdocking%2Bstation&qid=1674577758&s=electronics&sprefix=macbook%2Bpro%2Celectronics%2C96&sr=1-8&th=1